# Integrate $\int\frac{x^3}{(x^3+1)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

any ideas on how I could continue this integral

$$\int\frac{x^3}{(x^3+1)^2}dx$$

I am half way done, by entirely using fraction decomposition

$\int\frac{x^3}{(x^3+1)^2}dx=\int\frac{1}{x^3+1}dx-\int\frac{1}{(x^3+1)^2}dx$

$\frac{1}{x^3+1}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2-x+1}$ from which it follows that $A=\frac{1}{3}, B=-\frac{1}{3}, C=\frac{2}{3}$

$\frac{1}{x^3+1}=\frac{1}{3(x+1)}-\frac{x-2}{3(x^2-x+1)}$

$\int\frac{1}{3(x+1)}dx=\frac{1}{3}\ln|{x+1}|+C$

$\int\frac{x-2}{3(x^2-x+1)}dx=\frac{1}{3}\left(\int\frac{2x-1}{2(x^2-x+1)}dx-\int\frac{3}{2(x^2-x+1)}dx\right)=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln|{x^2-1+1}|-\frac{3}{2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}})\right)+C$

$\int\frac{dx}{(x^3+1)^2}=?$

This is the part where I am stuck currently, using fraction decomposition seems to take a lot of time and effort, could I be missing anything?

Comment: How about $v = x^3 + 1$?

Comment: Can not use u-substitution and using parts would just make it more complex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:  Try integrating by parts first, with $u=x$ and $dv={x^2\over(x^3+1)^2}dx$.

Comment: Amazing! This solves the problem!

Comment: I end up with $\int\frac{ln({x^3+1})}{3}dx$ from where I can not continue any further.

Comment: @user122673, try again.  You'd get $\ln(x^3+1)$ if the $dv$ were $x^2/(x^3+1)$, without the exponent $2$ in the denominator.  But because of the $2$, you get something simpler (and you should find your partial fractions work doesn't go to waste!).

Comment: Well fixed it (silly mistake), seems like it gets a familiar turn there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $x^3+1$ is not irreducible (as you have seen),

$$x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1).$$

You need to continue decomposing in order to compute the integral.